# How to send large iso images(size is more than 2gb) in java?

Tags: java

The problem is here client is requesting server to transfer a particular range of bytes under Range header. Based on that requested range only I have to send back that amount of bytes. How can I perform this in JAVA?

Answer (score 0):

1. Open file
2. Skip to `start` position
3. Read `X` bytes
4. Send them
5. Close file

*Java is not an acronym.*

Comment: For that which method can I use? FileInputStreamReader read method is not working like that...please kindly rply with proper code...